# Run 'bundle exec middleman server' with supervisor

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, supervisord

I'm working with [slate](https://github.com/lord/slate), which runs a web server with `bundle exec middleman server`. I'd like to persist this with supervisor, but I can't figure out how. Running the command normally from within the directory works just fine. The config I've tried is below, as is the error I get when running it.

How can I properly run this as a daemon?

supervisor .conf file:

```
[program:slate]
directory=/home/vaindil/slate
command=/home/vaindil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle exec middleman server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/slate.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/slate.out.log
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE:** Per Matt's request in the comments, I tried running Foreman and exporting to supervisord. I get a different error from that.

The output supervisord config:

```
[program:app-web-1]
command=bundle exec middleman server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile=/var/log/web-1.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/web-1.error.log
directory=/home/vaindil/slate
environment=PORT="4567"

[group:app]
programs=app-web-1
```

The errors:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than /
the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you /
upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
bundler: command not found: middleman
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Comment: I might suggest using Foreman to export to supervisor, and see if you get anything different. https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#EXPORT-FORMATS

Also, for what it's worth, when I search for your particular error, it has something to do with RVM and environment variables. Might be another place to start.

Comment: @Matt I tried Foreman, using `foreman start` works perfectly, but the exported output for supervisord does not work. I'll add that to the question momentarily.

Comment: So the problem is the `bundle` script has the following `#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks` line at the start. The `env` command cannot find the `ruby_executable_hooks` script in the same directory. I might require some `environment` settings in the `supervisor` configuration.

Comment: I added the correct paths to the `environment` in the `supervisor` config and that should have worked; however that did not work for me. The error still is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get it working:

`rvm wrapper ruby-version-here executable-hooks`

ex: `rvm wrapper ruby-2.3.1 executable-hooks`

Once I added that to the wrapper, then added the wrapper path to my `supervisor` configuration it all started working.

Your command might be like this now:

`command=/home/vaindil/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/bundle exec middleman server`

Comment: Thanks, I am using rbenv and passed the bundler path to the startup script and it worked. "/root/.rbenv/shims/bundler"